# Material showing up differently depending on face

Tags: materials

I've got a gun, and i applied a material on it, but on some faces, the same material shows up darker than everywhere else. I checked the normals, and they are okay. What is happening?
Image (note: the landscape is here to provide hdri lighting):[image]

EDIT: The problem affects the faces under the barrel, those which aren't emissive.

The Blend File: [image]

Comment: Can you point out some of the affected faces?

Comment: What is done? If your issue has been solved please post or have the person that solved it for you post. Ty

Comment: I think this is a shadow/enlightening and non planar surfaces

Comment: What is this? I carefully removed all distortion using mesh analysis.

Comment: I se nothing abnormal here, what faces are you talking about specifically? The darker faces at the bottom look different because they are pointing down where there is less light.

Comment: Shine as many lights as you want on them, they won't look the same as the others.